# CSS Transparent Windows

Tags: javascript, css, sass

This idea comes from the idea of an arcade cabinet. Let's say you have 2 layers in a project. Layer 1 with z-index of -1 has a background of blue. I want the upper most div to be black with the inner area of the div to be semi-transparent, similar to a window on an arcade cabinet. How would I solve this issue?

To give you an idea it would look like:
[Arcade Cabinet Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psnxv.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried yet any solution?

Comment: Also, I think you will want the overlay div to contain an image. 'filter' to provide the effect.

Comment: Share your code ?@Hamburguesa

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#s {
  border-radius: 7vh;
  width: 102vh;
  height: 77vh;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 50vw #000;
  transform: rotateX(-3deg);
  background: linear-gradient(0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) 1px, transparent 0) 0 / 1px 3px, url(https://picsum.photos/800/600) 0 0 /cover
}
```

```html
<div id="s"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that... in the way you want. You would need to have multiple layers compose the "cabinet" facade. These would sit on the top. The blue could be in the background at -1. If you wanted to then have the "semi-transparent" part in there, then that would probably be a separate layer.

The facade below is in four "pieces": top, right, bottom, left. The screen itself sits in one layer. The glare sits in another.

```css
.screen{
 z-index:-1;
 right:0;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;
 background-color:blue;
 position:absolute;
}
.screen div{
 margin-top:90px;
 color: yellow;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: fantasy;
}

.piece{
 z-index:1;
 background-color:black;
 position:absolute;
}
.top{
  height:4%;width:100%;
  top:0;left:0;
}
.bottom{
  height:4%;width:100%;
  bottom:0;left:0;
}
.right{
  height:100%;width:2%;
  top:0;right:0;
}
.left{
  height:100%;width:2%;
  top:0;left:0;
}
.glare{
 z-index:0;
 background: radial-gradient(75% 35%, rgba(200,200,200,0.5), rgba(240,240,240,0.3));
 right:0;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;
 position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="top piece"></div>
<div class="right piece"></div>
<div class="bottom piece"></div>
<div class="left piece"></div>
<div class="glare"></div>
<div class="screen">
  <div>press any button to continue...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using three layers. 
The Screen can be blue and behind that you have a big black div as the screen frame. On top of the screen you can put a transparent div. 
The problem you'd face when using two divs is that the frame of the screen would look grey instead of the desired black effect.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you need to think of layering in a different manner then how an arcade machine is built.

- The black screen bezel is the lowest layer (`#bezel`)
- The screen is the middle layer (`#screen`)
- The overlay is the top layer (`#overlay`)

```css
#bezel,
#overlay,
#screen {
  height: 240px;
  width: 256px;
}
#overlay,
#screen img {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#bezel {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 50px;
}
#overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<section id="bezel">
  <section id="overlay"></section>
  <section id="screen">
    <img src="https://www.mobygames.com/images/shots/l/116293-rad-racer-ii-nes-screenshot-driving-off-into-the-sunset.png" />
  </section>
</section>
```